# Можно в golang написать функцию конструктор или наследовать от другой функции?

Tags: golang, наследование, конструктор

Я пишу роутинг

```
import "github.com/gorilla/mux"
func main() {
    router := mux.NewRouter().StrictSlash(true)
    router.HandleFunc("/", Index)  
    router.HandleFunc("/api/:controller/:action", ApiHandler)
    и т.д.
```

И нужно выполнять определённые действия для всех контроллеров (проверку авторизации и т.д.). Можно ли один раз написать функцию с проверкой, а потом ко всем необходимым функциям её прицепить?

Я пока только вижу громоздкий вариант - это запуск функции-проверки  во всех функциях. Есть ли вариант конструктора или наследования?

`Решение`. Спасибо Ainar-G

```
type logWrapper struct {
    http.Handler
}

func (wr logWrapper) ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    log.Printf("%s %s %s\n", r.Method, r.URL, time.Now())
    wr.Handler.ServeHTTP(w, r)
}    

func main() {

    router := mux.NewRouter()
    s := http.StripPrefix("/static/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("./files/"))) 
    router.HandleFunc("/", Index)
    router.HandleFunc("/login", LogIn)
    router.HandleFunc("/logout", LogOut)   
        FileHandler := http.HandlerFunc(File) 

    router.Handle("/file.html", logWrapper{FileHandler})
    router.PathPrefix("/static/").Handler(s)
    http.Handle("/", router) 

    http.ListenAndServe(":5000", nil) 
} 

func Index(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprintln(w, "hello")
}

func File(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprintln(w, "это обрабатывается в обёртке)) ")
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Традиционно, это делается через обёртки (они же middleware). Например, обёртка для логгирования запросов:

```
type logWrapper struct {
    http.Handler
}

func (wr logWrapper) ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    log.Printf("%s %s %s\n", r.Method, r.URL, time.Now())
    wr.Handler.ServeHTTP(w, r)
}
```

С ней, роуты регистрируются так:

```
router.Handle("/", logWrapper{IndexHandler})  
router.Handle("/api/:controller/:action", logWrapper{APIHandler})
```

Если используются функции, их можно конвертировать в [`http.HandlerFunc`](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#HandlerFunc):

```
IndexHandler := http.HandlerFunc(IndexFunc)
router.Handle("/", logWrapper{IndexHandler})
APIHandler := http.HandlerFunc(APIHandlerFunc)
router.Handle("/api/:controller/:action", logWrapper{APIHandler})
```

Comment: Пишет cannot use handlers.File (type func(http.ResponseWriter, *http.Request)) as type http.Handler in field value:
        func(http.ResponseWriter, *http.Request) does not implement http.Handler (missing ServeHTTP method) . Как привести к одному типу?

Comment: Если у вас функция, то можно либо конвертнуть в `http.HandlerFunc`, либо в обёртке вместо `http.Handler` объявить `F func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request)` и дальше в методе `wr.F(w, r)`.

Comment: Я добавил описание. С типами не разберусь

Comment: У вас `Secure` - это не функция, а `http.Handler`, так что использовать надо `router.Handle` в таком случае.

Comment: А можете написать код? что именно писать и где?

Comment: См. правку. Рекомендую почитать [документацию к `net/http`](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/), потому что интерфейсы, которые она определяет, используются почти всеми веб-библиотеками.

Comment: Позвольте нам [продолжить обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25873/discussion-between-twors-and-ainar-g).

Comment: Написал полностью код. Почитал про обёртки. Что-то не пойму- где я делаю неправильно

Comment: Опечатался. `http.HandlerFunc`, а не `http.HandleFunc`. Первый - тип, второе - функция.

Comment: Урааа.....Заработало)))) Спасибо большое